# Opening multiple threads with an object and returning a result

Tags: multithreading, oop, c++11, std, unordered-map

I am trying to open multiple threads through a loop where each thread is an instance of a class which has its constructor overloaded that way it automatically runs the desired code, this function returns an unordered_list and I would like to retrieve it for that particular instance to then be appended to a final unordered_list

I have tried using futures and promises, but I end up confusing myself when I try. This project is meant to challenge me and help me learn multithreading in c++.

```
    //class to be instantiated per thread   
    class WordCounter {
    public:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> thisWordCount;
        std::string word;

        WordCounter(std::string filepath) {}//will be overloaded
        ~WordCounter() {}//destructor

        std::unordered_map<std::string, int>operator()(std::string filepath) const {}//overloaded constructor signature
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int>operator()(std::string currentFile) {//overloaded constructor implementation
            fstream myReadFile;
            myReadFile.open(currentFile);
            if (!!!myReadFile) {
                cout << "Unable to open file";
                exit(1); // terminate with error
            }
            else if (myReadFile.is_open()) {
                while (!myReadFile.eof()) {
                    while (myReadFile >> word) {
                        ++thisWordCount[word];
                    }
                }
            }
            myReadFile.close();

            return thisWordCount;
        }
    };


    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;//store instantiated threads using WordCounter
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, int> finalWordCount; //append result from each thread to this unordered_list only when a particular thread finish's reading a file
        vector<string> fileName = { "input1.txt" , "input2.txt" };//filepaths to the files used

        for (int i = 0; i < fileName.size(); ++i)//loop through vector of filepaths to open a thread for each file to then be processed by that thread
        {
            std::string currentFile = DIR + fileName[i];
            std::thread _newThread(new WordCount(currentFile); //is this how the thread would be created?
            threads.emplace_back(_newThread);//store new thread in a vector

//I want to read through the vector when a particular thread finishes and append that particular threads result to finalWordCount

        }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Multithreading your code

Let's start off by writing a multi-threaded `countWords` function. This will give us a high-level overview of what the code needs to do, and then we'll fill in the missing parts.

#### Writing `countWords`

`countWords` counts the word frequencies in each file in a vector of filenames. It does this in parallel.

**Overview of steps:**

- Create a vector of threads
- Provide a place to store the final result (this is the `finalWordCount` variable)
- Make a callback function for the `WordCounter` to call when it's done
- Start a new thread for each file with a `WordCounter` object.
- Wait for theads to finish
- return `finalWordCount`

A `WordCounter` object takes the filename as input when the thread starts.

**Missing parts:**

- We still need to write a `makeWordCounter` function

**Implemenation:**

```
using std::unordered_map;
using std::string; 
using std::vector; 

unordered_map<string, int> countWords(vector<string> const& filenames) {
    // Create vector of threads
    vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(filenames.size());

    // We have to have a lock because maps aren't thread safe
    std::mutex map_lock;

    // The final result goes here
    unordered_map<std::string, int> totalWordCount; 

    // Define the callback function
    // This operation is basically free
    // Internally, it just copies a reference to the mutex and a reference
    // to the totalWordCount
    auto callback = [&](unordered_map<string, int> const& partial_count) {
        // Lock the mutex so only we have access to the map
        map_lock.lock(); 
        // Update the map
        for(auto count : partial_count) {
            totalWordCount[count.first] += count.second; 
        }
        // Unlock the mutex
        map_lock.unlock(); 
    };

    // Create a new thread for each file
    for(auto& file : filenames) {
        auto word_counter = makeWordCounter(callback); 
        threads.push_back(std::thread(word_counter, file)); 
    }

    // Wait until all threads have finished
    for(auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join(); 
    }

    return totalWordCount; 
}
```

#### Writing `makeWordCounter`

Our function `makeWordCounter` is very simple: it just creates a `WordCounter` function that's templated on the callback.

```
template<class Callback>
WordCounter<Callback> makeWordCounter(Callback const& func) {
    return WordCounter<Callback>{func}; 
}
```

#### Writing a `WordCounter` class

Member variables:

- The callback function (we don't need anything else)

Functions

- `operator()` calls `countWordsFromFilename` with the filename
- `countWordsFromFilename` opens the file, makes sure it's OK, and calls `countWords` with the filestream
- `countWords` reads all the words in a filestream and calculates the count, then invokes the callback with the final count.

Because `WordCounter` is really simple, I just made it a struct. It only needs to store the `Callback` function, and by making the `callback` function public, we don't have to write a constructor (the compiler handles it automatically using aggregate initialization).

```
template<class Callback>
struct WordCounter {
    Callback callback;

    void operator()(std::string filename) {
        countWordsFromFilename(filename); 
    }
    void countWordsFromFilename(std::string const& filename) {
        std::ifstream myFile(filename);
        if (myFile) {
            countWords(myFile); 
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "Unable to open " + filename << '\n'; 
        }
    }
    void countWords(std::ifstream& filestream) {
        std::unordered_map<std::string, int> wordCount; 
        std::string word; 
        while (!filestream.eof() && !filestream.fail()) {
            filestream >> word; 
            wordCount[word] += 1;
        }
        callback(wordCount); 
    }
};
```

#### Complete code

You can see the complete code for `countWords` here: https://pastebin.com/WjFTkNYF

The only things I added were the `#include`s.

### Callbacks and templates 101 (at request of Original Poster)

Templates are a simple and useful tool to have when writing code. They can be used to eliminate mutual dependencies; make algorithms generic (so they can be used with whatever types you like); and they can even make code faster and more efficient by allowing you to avoid calls to virtual member functions, or to function pointers.

#### Templating a class

Let's look at a really simple class template representing a pair:

```
template<class First, class Second>
struct pair {
    First first;
    Second second; 
};
```

Here, we declared `pair` as a `struct` because we want all members to be public.

**Note that there's no `First` type, and no `Second` type.** When we use the names `First` and `Second`, what we're really saying is "in the context of the `pair` class, the name `First` will represent the `First` argument of the pair class, and the name `Second` will represent the second element of the pair class.

We could just have easily written it as:

```
// This is completely valid too
template<class A, class B>
struct pair {
    A first;
    B second; 
};
```

Using `pair` is pretty simple:

```
int main() {
    // Create pair with an int and a string
    pair<int, std::string> myPair{14, "Hello, world!"}; 

    // Print out the first value, which is 14
    std::cout << "int value:    " << myPair.first << '\n';
    // Print out the second value, which is "Hello, world!"
    std::cout << "string value: " << myPair.second << '\n';
}
```

Just like a normal class, `pair` can have member functions, a constructor, destructor... anything. Because `pair` is such a simple class, the compiler generate the constructor and destructor for us automatically, and we don't have to worry about them.

#### Templated functions

Templated functions look similar to regular functions. The only difference is that they have the `template` declaration before the rest of the function declaration.

Let's write a simple function to print a pair:

```
template<class A, class B>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, pair<A, B> pair) 
{
    stream << '(' << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << ')'; 
    return stream; 
}
```

We can give it any `pair` we want, as long as it knows how to print both elements of the pair:

```
int main() {
    // Create pair with an int and a string
    pair<int, std::string> myPair{14, "Hello, world!"}; 

    std::cout << myPair << '\n'; 
}
```

This outputs `(14, Hello, world)`.

#### Callbacks

There's no `Callback` type in C++. We don't need one. A callback is just something you use to indicate that something happened.

Let's look at a simple example. This function looks for progressively bigger numbers, and every time it finds one, it calls `output`, which is a parameter we provided. In this case, `output` is a callback, and we're using it to indicate that a new biggest number was found.

```
template<class Func>
void getIncreasingNumbers(std::vector<double> const& nums, Func output) 
{
    // Exit if there are no numbers
    if(nums.size() == 0) 
        return; 

    double biggest = nums[0]; 
    // We always output the first one
    output(biggest); 
    for(double num : nums) 
    {
        if(num > biggest) 
        {
            biggest = num; 
            output(num); 
        }
    }
}
```

We can use `getIncreasingNumbers` in a lot of different ways. For example, we can filter the numbers that weren't bigger than the previous one:

```
std::vector<double> filterNonIncreasing(std::vector<double> const& nums) 
{
    std::vector<double> newNums; 
    // Here, we use an & inside the square brackets
    // This is so we can use newNums by reference
    auto my_callback = [&](double val) { 
        newNums.push_back(val); 
    };
    getIncreasingNumbers(nums, my_callback); 
    return newNums; 
}
```

Or we can print them out:

```
void printNonIncreasing(std::vector<double> const& nums) 
{
    // Here, we don't put anything in the square brackts
    // Since we don't access any local variables
    auto my_callback = [](double val) {
        std::cout << "New biggest number: " << val << '\n'; 
    };
    getIncreasingNums(nums, my_callback); 
}
```

Or we can find the biggest gap between them:

```
double findBiggestJumpBetweenIncreasing(std::vector<double> const& nums)
{
    double previous; 
    double biggest_gap = 0.0; 
    bool assigned_previous = false;
    auto my_callback = [&](double val) {
        if(not assigned_previous) {
            previous = val; 
            assigned_previous = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            double new_gap = val - previous; 
            if(biggest_gap < new_gap) {
                biggest_gap = new_gap; 
            }
        }
    };
    getIncreasingNums(nums, my_callback); 
    return biggest_gap;
}
```

Comment: I didn't provide unessasary extra code, hence the int main needs a return 0; and currentFile is the DIR(directory) + the current filePath we are using. So we would pass in currentPath into the WordCounter constructor I think. which gets used in the overloaded constructor implementation in my class

Comment: Your operator() overloads in WordCounter take arguments, and to have to provide those arguments when starting a std::thread with a WordCounter. Also, you can’t copy a thread; you either have to move it into the vector with std::move, or construct it at the call site (which is what I did in the above code)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, very interesting! The argument passed into the constructor is a string containing the particular file's path from combining the directory and the filename which the loop goes through which then gets read at myReadFile.open()

Comment: Sure thing! Just make sure you don’t double-combine the directory and the file name (so maybe print out the filename in the WordCounter operator() just to check)

Comment: The important thing I now need to figure out is how to read the returned value per thread instance. Then I can then append that result(returned value) to finalWordCount concurrently, without having a race condition or other undesired consequences of using threads, which i assume I then use std::mutex to provide a semaphore(token) for finalWordCount? and getting the returned result would mean using futures right? How is that implemented?

Comment: Have WordCounter store a pointer or a reference to the place where it’s supposed to stick the result. Alternatively, have it store a callback that gets called when it completes, and make the callback responsible for updating the result. If you make `finalWordCount` an atomic int (look up std::atomic), then you won’t have to do any locking when you update it

Comment: Would you like me to update my answer with a simple example of how to use these?

Comment: Sure! That would be very helpful

Comment: I re-did the answer! Let me know what you think!

Comment: Sure! Lemme know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Could you explain how you used templates and callbacks? They are areas I have not touched, all I knew before was you could call a function in line with a lambda function [=](){ somecodetoexecute; }. more specifically, there is a Callback datatype? Is this one way of using callbacks, or fairly standard?

Comment: There's not a callback datatype, and this is just one way of using callbacks. I added a "Templates and callbacks 101" to the answer!

Comment: Fantastic! I re-read and saw how silly my question was! One last thing... wouldn't making the finalWordCount resource a reference in every thread make the entire process sequential again? By having each thread access it one at a time with a semaphore(mutex), it may ruin the entire point of multithreading right? No performance gains over just sequentially reading these files in without threads.

Comment: There's no thread-safe way to add elements to a map, so you have to use a mutex. If you already knew which words to check for, then you could put those words in the map beforehand, and then you could do stuff with atomics (avoiding any locking), but you wouldn't be able to add new words to the map without a mutex.  

The synchronization step (the part a mutex has to be used for) is usually the bottleneck of a parallel code, but you'll still get a speed-up as long as most of the work can be done before synchronization (rather than during synchronization).

Comment: That being said, the bottleneck in the above code is reading files. Your hard drive can only read so much data per second, and it's likely that even single-threaded code can process the data faster than it can be read from the hard drive. Your best bet would be reading the file on one thread and processing it on a different thread.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your insight & use of templating, it forced me to learn a bit more about cpp. With reading & writing being from the same buffer, that would be the ultimate cap in terms of fully leveraging multithreading in this scenario(and many IO problems to-be solved). Is it possible to make multiple buffers that can divide and conquer data concurrently, assuming the order in which data is read does not matter? And during the divide and conquer process, there could be message queues communicating progress, and intent whilst reading. eg: start and end range of bytes that will be read?

Comment: When you talk about buffers, are you referring to file buffers? Or are you referring to the std::unordered_map used to generate partial counts of the word frequencies on a per-file basis? In the case of file IO, the speed of a buffer is usually limited by the hard drive or SSD itself, so making multiple buffers for the same file won't result in faster processing. On the other hand, if you have separate files coming in from separate drives, or if you have a stream of data coming in from the network, then it might make sense to have multiple IO buffers.